# If you have a Nintendo Network ID on your Wii U and you get another Wii U, can you log in on the other Wii U with your same account?

Tags: wii-u, nintendo-network-id

I got a Wii U, and I made myself a Nintendo Network ID. Then one day I made my sister a Nintendo Network ID,too. Now, my sister is getting a Wii U, and we don't know if she can use her account on the Wii U she's getting, or if she will have to create a new account. Please let us know if she can log in with her account on the Wii U she's gonna get. **NOTE**: I didn't know there was a similar question. If I knew why would I ask the same question instead of just reading another one. And honestly I didn't even know that NNID meant Nintendo Network ID. I don't know what to do if it's EXCATLY the same....